# aws_embedded_metrics package not working in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I have installed the aws_embedded package and I am trying to import the module in Pycharm. Unfortunately, it is not working.

**Code**

```
import json
from aws_embedded_metrics import metric_scope

@metric_scope
def my_handler(metrics):
    metrics.put_dimensions({"Foo": "Bar"})
    metrics.put_metric("ProcessingLatency", 100, "Milliseconds")
    metrics.set_property("AccountId", "123456789012")
    metrics.set_property("RequestId", "422b1569-16f6-4a03")
    metrics.set_property("DeviceId", "61270781-c6ac-46f1")

    return {"message": "Hello!"}
```

[image: Terminal with the Package Installed]
[image: Python Console Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Installation of aws-embedded-metrics using pip**

You are making mistake in installation, this is the correct way to install.

```
pip3 install aws-embedded-metrics
```

**Import of aws-embedded-metrics**

```
import json
from aws_embedded_metrics import metric_scope


@metric_scope
def my_handler(metrics):
    metrics.put_dimensions({"Foo": "Bar"})
    metrics.put_metric("ProcessingLatency", 100, "Milliseconds")
    metrics.set_property("AccountId", "123456789012")
    metrics.set_property("RequestId", "422b1569-16f6-4a03")
    metrics.set_property("DeviceId", "61270781-c6ac-46f1")

    return {"message": "Hello!"}
```